# Dining room ceiling repair

Tags: drywall, ceiling-fan, plaster

So the long story shortened is my wife swapped out fans and now I have a gap in my ceiling where the old fan was and the new fan is.  Sadly the dilemma doesn't stop there so I bought a 2 part medallion and upon attempting to install it the connection for the colander is up flush with the ceiling meaning that I cannot get a medallion up between the fan and the ceiling.  Am I potentially missing an idea? I thought about patching the drywall but that also doesn't seem like a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post pictures of the fan and the medalion?

Comment: Yes I can in a little bit.